# Convert tags to html entities

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

Is it possible to convert html tags to html entities using javascript/jquery using any way possible such as regex or some other way. If yes, then how?

**Example:**

`<div>` should be converted to `&lt;div&gt;`

**Note:** I am not talking about server-side languages.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try this function for the HTML special characters:

```
function htmlencode(str) {
    return str.replace(/[&<>"']/g, function($0) {
        return "&" + {"&":"amp", "<":"lt", ">":"gt", '"':"quot", "'":"#39"}[$0] + ";";
    });
}
```

Comment: Why not `apos` instead of `#39`?

Comment: @Eli Grey: The *apos* entity was introduced in XML 1.0 (and thus defined for XHTML) but it is not defined in HTML 4. (See http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#C_16)

Comment: What a terrific tiny piece of code. Took me a minute to see what you were doing there! You've made my evening.

Comment: return "&" + {"&":"amp", "<":"lt", ">":"gt", '"':"quot", "'":"#39"}[$0] -> Is it something existing only within regular expression in JS ? As from what I see It does the comparison between the matchings patterns in the array ·[$0] and the literral object we defined. I've never met such syntaxe before and I find it very handy, if there are any others tips such this one I'm interested.

Comment: @Azuk `$0` is a variable that holds the matched string of the whole pattern. It is used to lookup the mapped value in an object, which uses the characters in the character class `[&<>"']` as property name and returns the corresponding property value. You could also have used a variable to hold the object like `var map = {…}` and then access it with `map[$0]`. The notation `{…}[$0]` is just more compact and unfortunately less obvious.

Answer (score 8):

As you tagged with jquery, a jQuery-powered solution should work for you:

```
$("<div>").text("<div>bleh</div>whatever").html()
```

Replace the argument to the text-method with whatever markup you want to escape.

Answer (score 2):

*I have 2 fast and small implementations for encoding HTML safely.*

You can encode all characters in your string:

```
function encode(e){return e.replace(/[^]/g,function(e){return"&#"+e.charCodeAt(0)+";"})}
```

Or just target the main characters to worry about (&, inebreaks, <, >, " and ') like:

```js
function encode(r){
return r.replace(/[\x26\x0A\<>'"]/g,function(r){return"&#"+r.charCodeAt(0)+";"})
}

var myString='Encode HTML entities!\n"Safe" escape <script></'+'script> & other tags!';

test.value=encode(myString);

testing.innerHTML=encode(myString);

/*************
* \x26 is &ampersand (it has to be first),
* \x0A is newline,
*************/
```

```html
<p><b>What JavaScript Generated:</b></p>

<textarea id=test rows="3" cols="55"></textarea>

<p><b>What It Renders Too In HTML:</b></p>

<div id="testing">www.WHAK.com</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In JQuery:

```
$('<div/>').text('This is fun & stuff').html(); // evaluates to "This is fun &amp; stuff"
```

http://debuggable.com/posts/encode-html-entities-with-jquery:480f4dd6-13cc-4ce9-8071-4710cbdd56cb

Answer (score 1):

If you have the variable and you want to insert it on a div, you can call text().

```
var myVar = "<span><strong>Some vars</strong> Some var extra</span>";
$("div").text(myVar);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var d = "<div>"
d = d.replace(/<|>/g, function(chr){
    return chr == "<" ? "&lt;" : "&gt;"
})
console.log(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a concise way of doing this using `String.prototype.replace()` and regular expressions as follows:

```
var tag = "<h1>This should </h1>be bold<h2> and big</h2>";
var escapedTag = tag.replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
```