# How do i convert html tags to normal string using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert tags to html entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613582/convert-tags-to-html-entities)

I am building a snippets area to a friend's site, and i need to know how to convert html tags to normal text so the page will show the tags.

Like here in the code:

```
<img>
```

so the tag will be seen and not become to a normal html tag,

And all this using javascript or jQuery.

What I got now is something like that:

```
<pre><code>THE USERS CODE</code></pre>
```

and it still hide the html tags and make them active.
thx :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use

```
function htmlEntities(str) {
    return String(str).replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
}
```

SOURCE: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/htmlentities-for-javascript/

Comment: I think it will not work means if when we have string data having with >< , it will remove these both and we will have incomplete data.

Answer (score -4):

Use Jquery and instead of `$('something').html()` use `$('something').text()` checkout http://api.jquery.com/text/

Comment: That would remove the tags completely. OP wants to display them as they are.

Comment: Sorry I was meaning $('something').text(<YOUR STUFF IN HERE>).html() The same as what was suggested by Jörn Zaefferer on the duplicated answer