# Convert a .val() into string jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery function that gets the value from a form input text object named `content` in which a user can enter an HTML tag in the form. For example, the user types "Sample" with `<b>` tags. Once submit is fired, jQuery gets the value from `content`.

```
var content = $('[name=content]').val();
```

My problem is if the user has a tag lets say a `<b>` tag, I want to output the raw html string to the user instead of having it rendered.

How can I do it? Any help will be much appreciated, I'm new to jQuery.

Comment: i tried .html() and .text() but it won't work, i think because values came from the user.

Comment: How/where are you showing the output to the user?

Comment: @am not i ma - I want to display it by appending it to a div.

Comment: this is what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/ApyJt/

Answer (score 10):

`.val()` already returns a string.
You're asking how to display that string without parsing it as HTML.

Call `.text()`.

Comment: I already tried it but it did not work, when i check the tutorials, .text() I think does not work when it is a user input value, can .text() really work for input tag values?

Comment: @SimonBASS: looks like you're still thinking we understand what you mean. Unfortunately we don't

Comment: @SimonBASS: No.  The value from `val()` is an ordinary string.  Your problem comes from _displaying_ the value.  You need to call the `.text(...)` setter.

Comment: You need to understand what's going on here, or you won't get anywhere.

Comment: I think he'd like to show <b> as &lt;b&gt; (shows literal <>) from the input value, whereas `text()` discards it

Comment: @SiGanteng: I'm not sure what you're saying; `.text()` is exactly what he needs.

Comment: @SLaks Yeah just tried my suggestion and it actually shows literal `<b>`... Sorry about that :s, shoulda RTFM next time

Comment: .text() really won't work, Okay I'll explain that I'm trying to achieve, I have a wiki which the user can preview what he typed before he can submit it. A user can place tags, what I want to achieve is that when I display the value to the user, I want the tags to be seen instead of it being executed

Comment: @SimonBASS: Yes.  To do that, you need to display it using `.text()`.

Comment: @SimonBASS my demo is based on this answer, I think you should accept this if that demo is helping you :)

Comment: @SimonBASS: it's not `$(...).val().text()`, it's just `$(...).text()` or `$(...).text($(...).val())`; otherwise, modify your question and show what the input is and what you expect the output to be.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so it sounds like you are wanting to display the code without the browser rendering it.  Perhaps you want to [convert your tags to html enttities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613582/convert-tags-to-html-entities)

Answer (score 0):

Without jQuery, you would do:

```
document.getElementsByName('content')[0].value;
```

to get exactly the stirng that the user entered.

#### Edit

Now I get it, you are writing the value as the innerHTML of another element and you want the literal text displayed, not the markup. So continuing with a sans-jQuery example:

```
<script>
// Set the text content of an element
var setText = (function() {
    var d = document.createElement('div');
    if (typeof d.textContent == 'string') {
      d = null;
      return function(el, text) {
        el.textContent = text;
      };
    } else if (typeof d.innerText == 'string') {
      d = null;
      return function(el, text) {
        el.innerText = text;
      };
    }
}());
</script>

<input name="content">
<button onclick="
  setText(document.getElementById('d0'), 
          document.getElementsByName('content')[0].value);
">get value</button>
<div id="d0"></div>
```

Or as SLaks suggests (rather cryptically):

```
$('#d0').text($('[name=content]').val());
```

Though I don't know why it wasn't in his or her answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was also having this problem.  I fixed it using the following cheat:

```
var val = $("#item").val() + "";
```