# Javascript: Replace one or more identical characters with the same number of another character?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to escape some special characters from a JS string, but I can only replace one or more occurrences with a single character.

For example, I want to replace & with `&amp;` but when I escape this string: `&&&` I get `&amp;&&`.

I've been using

```
input = input.replace(/&/g,"&amp;");
```

I know that the solution to this problem probably has to do with using an anonymous function, however I also need to escape about 10 other characters. I can't see a way to pass the replacement as a variable to the function. Does that mean I'll have to write 11 separate functions?

Comment: How are you executing it & verifying the result? It should work as advertised http://jsfiddle.net/RCmpR/

Comment: `'&&&'.replace(/&/g,'&amp;');` works just as expected.

Comment: If I go to your jsfiddle link I see &amp;&amp;&amp;, but if I execute the same code in firefox I see an alert that says &&&

Comment: Odd it works for me, what about if you console.log() it ?

Comment: Ok, I figured it out :( I was typing in "$$$".replace(/&/g,"&amp;"); and I was seeing three dollar signs. Also, I need to go to the generated source to see the html entities. This morning has been the perfect storm of stupidity.

Comment: To answer the other part, you don't need 11 funcs; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613582/convert-tags-to-html-entities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is okay, it seems that you have tested it without `/g`.

You can also use: `replace(/(&)/g,"$1amp;");`

See and test the code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mED5f/).

Comment: Thanks. It seems JS still works, it seems I shouldnt use document.write to test this kind of stuff.